# Multiple inheritance from two abstract classes (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qgraphicsitem, dynamic-cast

I have my abstract class (`A`), which describes a field trip and Qt base class `QGraphicsItem`, which describes the Qt functions for controlling items . I want to inherit from these classes to their items .

The problem is that the list of items stored in a `QList <QGraphicsItem *>`, making it impossible to access the fields `A ::` directly, and do not want to use `dynamic_cast` . What are the other options?

It is important that the item may not be the final child, ie it can be inherited from other items (as well through multiple inheritance ) .

In `QList <QGraphicsItem *>` be kept only the elements inherited from `A` and `QGraphicsItem`. What are your suggestions ? Thank you for your help.

UPD1:
this code:

```
    QList<QGraphicsItem *> items=scene->items();
    for(int i=0;i<items.size();++i){
        std::cerr<<"\n"<<items.at(i)->entity::getX();
    }
```

(`entity` is `A`) throw an error:

> `/home/user/works/cpp/QT/Objcts/src/mainwindow.cpp:87: error: 'entity'
>   is not a base of 'QGraphicsItem'
>            std::cerr<<"\n"<<items.at(i)->entity::getX();
>                                                  ^`

Comment: So, you inherit from two base classes, and you need to disambiguate your member accesses? That's what the scope operator was designed for `::`.

Comment: I understand that it will be necessary to specify the scope: `instance.A::methodFromA()` or `instance.QGraphicsItem::methodFromQt ()`.  But when you try to retrieve an item from the list and call the method in such a way, I get an error because will be returned to the type of `QGraphicsItem*`, which is known about the methods of `A`.

Comment: I do not understand the question... what does this mean `making it impossible to access the fields A ::` -> You cannot access the child members directly either with good design, so how is this relevant to A? I cannot get it. Or you mean methods, too, by "field" and not just data members? This question is vague as it stands. I think you want to add code to actually demonstrate your issue. If you just ask how to avoid dynamic_casting, well, you cannot, well, that is not fair, you would need to use qobject_cast, but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: I updated the main message, to save the code format.

Comment: Maybe it's more useful to post (ask) what you're trying to achieve (ie. what problem you're trying to solve), since that way we could try and help you on the right track (we could help you organize your data structures and classes).

Comment: I began studying graphics in Qt and want to implement a hierarchy of graphical objects and make them move within `QGraphicsView`, as well as to react to certain events, such as mouse movements and collisions .
The problem in the implementation of that `QGraphicsScene :: items ()` returns a `QList <QGraphicsItem *>`, although I pass overeat its type field containing both classes. Even though the fact that the de facto field contained in the structure , access to them to obtain I can not, because in the parent class does not contain me interested field.

Comment: As a workaround , you can simultaneously store `std::vector <entity*>` and refer to it , but it is very slow and stupid decision. I would like to make it more beautiful, or at least get a hint of how this can be done with one common parent `QGraphicsItem`

Comment: Your question title mentions multiple inheritance, but the discussion proceeds as if you are doing plain single inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /home/user/works/cpp/QT/Objcts/src/mainwindow.cpp:87: error: 'entity' is not a base of 'QGraphicsItem' std::cerr<<"\n"<entity::getX();

You are trying to access a base class, whereas your entity class (weirdly named without CamelCase) is not inheriting that.

Right, so this is the use case for which dynamic casts, like `dynamic_cast` in C++ was invented. You should utilize it.

That being said, for `QObjects`, it is even better to use the `qobject_cast` in the Qt world rather than the raw `dynamic_cast`. QGraphicsItem is intentionally not QObject, although your other base (entity) might be, but that is not relevant.

This code should get you going:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem *> items = scene->items();
foreach (GraphicsItem* item, items) {
    entity *e = dynamic_cast<entity*>(item);
    if (e)
        qDebug() << e->getX();
}
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this code, but the concept is valid, I think.

There is no need for neither stderr, nor explicit indexing loop. You could use the Qt debug functionality to print as you wish, and foreach to go through the elements.

Also, in the Qt world, "getX" is not really a common convention. People tend to prefer to drop the "get" prefix in favor of less typing.

Comment: I can not use `qobject_cast` as `QGraphicsItem` not inherit from `QObject`. `dynamic_cast` is possible, but not desirable.

Comment: Yep, I agree. I was actually looking into that. I recommend dynamic_cast.

Comment: It is a pity that there is no normal solutions. Made it a rule not to use `dynamic_cast` in running applications. Thank you for your help. 
P.S. let the question a little hung open, and if asked to do in a week will not, I will close.

Comment: I am not sure why dynamic_cast is not a normal solution. It was designed for this use case.

Comment: Qt offers `qgraphicsitem_cast`, don't know if it's applicable.

Comment: @Oktalist: as far as I understand A is not a QGI, so perhaps not, but I cannot be sure. I am not particularly good at QGV.